# How to unregister chartjs-plugin-datalabels globally?

Tags: angular, charts

I am trying to unregister chartjs plugin globally as per
https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/guide/getting-started.html#registration

My angular app strucrture

layout  ---->

```
module a---> lazy loaded
      component a1---> chart js chart

module b ----> lazy loaded 
      component b1---> chart js chart
module c---->lazy loaded
```

These components fetch my options from as .ts file

I am using a common ts file

my .ts file

```
import ChartDataLabels from "chartjs-plugin-datalabels";

Chart.plugins.unregister(ChartDataLabels);
// a function which return chart options to component
get myChartOptions()
{
var options = new Options();  //my class
let plugin = options.getPlugin();  //another .ts file which assign value
return options;
}

Expected: Chartjs Data Plugin will get unregistered itself at load.
Actual:   Plugin is not getting itself unregistered. Datalabels are 
          being in on component change also.

How to globally unregister the plugin in .ts file ??
```

Answer (score 4):

Only solution I've found for this to work is if you disable it on every instance of chart.
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#disable-plugins

Example:

```
options: {
    plugins: {
        p1: false   // disable plugin 'p1' for this instance
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the official suggested way. However the type might not be declared correctly for ts (`Type 'false' has no properties in common with type '_DeepPartialObject<PluginOptionsByType<"line">>`)

Comment: In some plugins there is option to enable, so you may alter your code to this: 

`plugins: {
pluginName: {
enable: false 
}
}`

Answer (score 3):

In your top file import :

```
ChartDataLabels from "chartjs-plugin-datalabels"
Chart from "chart.js"
```

now disable the plugin :

```
Chart.plugins.unregister(ChartDataLabels);
```

I use React, those three lines are in my index.js before the render method.

You can now locally enable the plugin by adding to your chart Component:

> > plugins={[ChartDataLabels]}

```
     <Pie 
                type="pie"
                data={data}
                borderWidth="10"
                plugins={[ChartDataLabels]}
                ...
```